# firebase deploy permission error

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a firebase app (following the hosting quickstart guide). I ran firebase bootstrap and picked leadersboard template. However, on following the on-screen instructions i.e. go into app directory and run firebase deploy, I get a "Permission error - You do not have permission to use this firebase." I'm new to firebase so I'm sure I'm missing something.

I'm running firebase ver 1.2.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run `firebase init` once and specify *your own* Firebase app. After that you can run `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Have you run `firebase login` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and seemed to resolve by changing line in firebase.json:

from:

```
"firebase": "some-name.firebase.com",
```

to:

```
"firebase": "some-name",
```

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to delete the .json log and package file in your project and then try these commands
after this command, you don't need to verify your account again

```
firebase login:ci
```

you need to deploy token with

```
firebase deploy --token
```